# Process creation failed with error: Access is denied when starting project in debug mode

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core project targeting net4.6.1
The following error is thrown every time I try to start the project with debugging, from both VS2017 and command line using `dotnet run`.

[image]

The csproj is the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModule</AspNetCoreModuleName>
    <StartupObject></StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\pathToAnotherProject\myproject.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I can mention that I have a single startup project created as an ASP.NET Core project and multiple .net core class library projects targeting net461.

Any idea where the problem comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to enable 'use managed compatibility mode' in the debugging>general section of VS2017 options.

Comment: Yes, no success with that